# Trouble with tea?

Tags: support, status-completed, tea

This [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54775/what-is-the-shortest-ph-d-thesis) has a link to [this](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/946/shortest-phd-thesis/) one on the old-meta-now-tea site, but when I clicked on it, I got this:

A fatal, non-recoverable error has occurred

Technical information (for support personel):

Error Message
The connection to the database failed:
Affected Elements
MySQL.OpenConnection();
The error occurred on or near: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'mathoverflow'@'satis.dreamhost.com' (using password: YES)
For additional support documentation, visit the Lussumo Documentation website at: lussumo.com/docs

The same thing happens when I click on a link to tea that I get from Google.

I don't know what any of that technical stuff means. Does it mean the old meta posts are gone? or does it just mean there's some other way to get there?

Comment: Maybe it's time to switch to coffee. Or perhaps something stronger? How about vodka.mathoverflow.net?

Comment: May be time to switch to mysqli or PDO, as mysql_connect() is deprecated! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Fixed, sorry.

I broke something while making the demo [archiving service](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2447/archiving-of-mathoverflow-threads) accessible.